# Alternative to UNIQUE contstraint for nullable columns

Tags: sql-server, null, unique-constraint

SQL Server allows you to apply a `UNIQUE` constraint, but its behaviour is odd: you cannot have more than one `NULL` in such a column.

My reading of the meaning of `NULL` and its normal behaviour, as well as the way other DMBS products work, is that `NULL` should be ignored. Instead, it appears to be compared, and so multiple NULLs are treated as duplicates.

I would regard this as contrary to the normal behaviour of `NULL`, as well as unfortunate. For example, it should be possible to indicate that a mobile phone number, *if known*, is unique.

If that is the case, how can we define a `UNIQUE` column which *does* allow more than one `NULL` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server **2008** and newer, you can create **filtered indices** that e.g. exclude NULL values:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED UNIQUE INDEX IX_SomeName
ON dbo.YourTableName(Columns)
WHERE Column1 IS NOT NULL
```